# Backup and Restore Nexus OSS 3

Tags: nexus, docker-registry, sonatype, maven-central, npmjs

I was wondering if there is a standard way to backup and restore a Nexus OSS 3 Artifact Repository.

Is it enough to backup the "data" directory and copy it to a running new instance?

I use different types of repositories - Maven, NPM, Docker etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Nexus Repository Manager 3.2 there will be a supported Backup/Restore feature. Your approach seems fine, a few notes:

- back up your data directory while Repository Manager is stopped (prevents db files being in an inconsistent state)
- test your restoration procedure to ensure it works

If you run into issues, please file them here so we can be aware: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS